# array with aftercorr dependency never starts in slurm

Tags: hpc, slurm

I am trying to write two arrays of identical size in SLURM and have each job in array #2 start after the corresponding job in #1 has completed. As far as I understand this is the exact use case of `--dependency=aftercorr:#jobid` in SLURM as per [one-to-one dependency between two job arrays in SLURM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742023/one-to-one-dependency-between-two-job-arrays-in-slurm)

However, when I do the below, the second array is left PENDING although many jobs in #1 have completed:

```sh
sbatch --mem=30g -c 2 --time 10:0:0 -e %A.%a.out -o %A.%a.out --array=1-977%200 ./step1.sh
# Store the array ID as $array1
# wait 1 hour, some of them show as COMPLETED
sbatch --mem=30g -c 2 --time 10:0:0 -e %A.%a.out -o %A.%a.out --array=1-977%200 --dependency=aftercorr:$array1 ./step2.sh
# This just remains PENDING forever
```

Comment: Is this a typo? your second line has `afterok`, not `aftercorr`

Comment: Yes typo, thanks Damien, it should be `aftercorr`. Correcting it now.

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with the duration of the jobs. If `step1.sh` and `step2.sh` are both simple fast scripts such as `sleep 15` there is no problem. However the situation I describe does arise when the jobs take several hours to complete.